# Why we use memset to fill the structure with value 0, in socket programming c?

Tags: c, sockets, struct, memset

```
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 

// Creating socket file descriptor 
if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
    perror("socket creation failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 

memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
```

In my previous work on structs i didn't fill the structures with value 0, but here in socket we always reset, fill 0, the struct before using it. Why is it important to fill 0 the structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the variables are declared as static storage duration, they will have an *arbitrary* value upon creation. Hence, it's always a good idea to set them to a known value *before* using them.

For example, if your next step after `socket()` is a `connect()` or `bind()`, they will very much want a specific structure value for client or server respectively.

It's no different really to the function:

```
void xyzzy(void) {
    int plugh;
    printf("%d\n", plugh);
}
```

inasmuch as it may print *any* value.

Answer (score 0):

*In continuation of @paxdiablo explanation -*

You may define a `const` `static` instance of the `struct` with the initial values.

```
static const struct sockaddr_in EmptyStruct;
```

A struct initializer may be used to set desired initial values (could be all 0es as by memset)

Then every time you want to reset the struct you can by

```
servaddr = EmptyStruct;
cliaddr = EmptyStruct;
```